# Differentiation of $x$ to the power of $y$ with respect to $x$

Tags: derivatives

As the title suggests, I need to differentiate $x$ to the power of $y$ with respect to $x$. Not sure how to start. Do I need to take natural log on both sides?

That is: $\dfrac{d}{dx}x^y=?$

Comment: $\frac{dx^y}{dx} = yx^{y-1}$. Did you mean to say, differentiate with respect to $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $$\frac{d(x^y)}{dx}$$

One of the ways could be:

Let $f(x)=x^y\implies \ln f(x)=y \cdot \ln x$

Using [Chain Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html) for the Left hand side,
$$\frac{\ln f(x)}{dx}=\frac{\ln f(x)}{d f(x)}\frac{d f(x)}{dx}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

and  [Product Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProductRule.html) of Differentiation  for the Right,
$$\frac{d(y \cdot \ln x)}{dx}=y\cdot \frac{d(\ln x)}{dx}+\ln x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\ln x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac 1x\cdot y$$

$$\implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac yx$$

$$\implies f'(x)=f(x)\left(\ln x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac yx\right)=x^y\left(\ln x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac yx\right)$$

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that $y$ is a function of $x$. If $y$ is constant, then this reduces to $\frac{dx^y}{dx}=yx^{y-1}$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, yes this a general solution like the other

Answer (score 1):

As $x^y=(e^{\ln x})^y=e^{y\ln x}$

$$\frac{d(x^y)}{dx}=\frac{d(e^{y\ln x})}{dx}$$

$$=\frac{d(e^{y\ln x})}{d(y\ln x)}\cdot \frac{ d(y\ln x)}{dx}$$ (applying [Chain Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html))

$$=e^{y\ln x}\left(y\cdot \frac{d(\ln x)}{dx}+\ln x\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

$$=x^y\left(y\cdot\frac1x+\ln x\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$